How do I avoid repetition in JavaScript?
How could this be done without repeating "DoTheNextThing();"?
    if (dosomething)
        DoSomething(function () {
            DoTheNextThing();
        })
    else
        DoTheNextThing();

I haven't tried anything else because I can't think of anything else to try.

dosomething ? DoSomething(DoTheNextThing) : DoTheNextThing();

Why does it matter? What do you gain by not repeating the name of the function that you won't lose in making it harder to read the code?

It's not pretty, but you can use a function that just calls its argument, and assign it conditionally to a variable.
const f = dosomething ? DoSomething : cb => cb();
f(DoTheNextThing);


Instead of DoSomething, choose a function that does nothing and then calls the callback:
function DoNothing(callback) { callback(); }

(dosomething ? DoSomething : DoNothing)(DoTheNextThing);


However, assuming DoSomething is an asynchronous function, you really should rewrite it to return a promise, then use async/await for much cleaner code:
if (dosomething)
    await DoSomething();
DoTheNextThing();


Besides what was shared already by @Barmar which works perfectly for a callback-based approach, I'd only add to consider switching to async/await to improver readability further more.
await (condition ? DoSomething() : Promise.resolve())

await DoNextThin()

